# Тестирование и проблема очередей в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Имееться простой достаточно тест на *Laravel*. Ну примерно следующего содержания.

`$this->json('post', route('...'))->assertOk();`

После запуска получаю в консоле такую ошибку:

**Fatal error: Uncaught Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher] is not instantiable. in ...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:1093**

В контроллере который обрабатывает запрос после ответа идет еще сброс кэша. `CacheClearJob::dispatch();`

В самом Job классе просто вызов `\Cache::forget('key')`

Версия *Laravel* 8, *PHP* 7.4

UPD: вызов очистки кэша через register_shutdown_function() в конструкторе. Это и стало причиной проблеммы, добавляю в описание т.к. этот момент был только на скрине.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибка воспроизводится только в тестах? Кажется, что это должно касаться и обычного запуска

Comment: @nomnoms12 удивительно но нет. при обычном запуске все хорошо отрабатывает. причем сам тест работает.  Tests:  1 passed . после всех тестов в консоли появляется эта ошибка. Если закоментировать CacheClearJob::dispatch() то нет ёё.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, выложить часть файла `config/app.php`? Мне интересно, как там выглядит импорт `BusServiceProvider`

Comment: @nomnoms12 хмм подозреваю что не в том дело. Вот смотрите, я закоментировал тот код что с очередями. В приложении в сервис провайдере регистрируется некий сервис

        $this->app->singleton('environment-service', function ($app): EnvironmentService {
            return new EnvironmentService();
        });
теперь проблемма с ним, не находит его. - Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class environment-service does not exist

Comment: @nomnoms12 используеться app('envinonment-service') и в приложении в обычном режиме нормально работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`register_shutdown_function()` запускается, когда свою работу завершает не только сам тест, но и PHPUnit. Я расставил в разных файлах вывод того, что сейчас выполняется:

```
echo sprintf("%s called\n", __METHOD__);
```

Затем запустил, и получилось так:

```
Tests\Feature\Order\OrderCreatedTest::testOrderCreated called
App\Domain\Order\Controllers\OrderController::order called
Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::tearDown called

   PASS  Tests\Feature\Order\OrderCreatedTest
  ✓ order created

  Tests:  1 passed
  Time:   0.15s

App\Domain\Order\Controllers\OrderController::shutdown called
```

Получается, порядок такой:

1. запуск теста
2. запуск контроллера
3. запуск `tearDown()`
4. запуск метода `shutdown()`, который был зарегистрирован через `register_shutdown_function()` в контроллере

`TestCase`, от которого отнаследован тест, имеет 2 важных метода:

- `setUp()` - создает экземпляр приложения, бутсрапит его. На этом экземпляре, собственно, и прогоняются тесты.
- `tearDown()`, который "прибирается": `$this->app->flush()`. Что в этом `flush()` происходит?

```
public function flush()
{
    parent::flush();

    $this->buildStack = [];
    $this->loadedProviders = [];
    $this->bootedCallbacks = [];
    $this->bootingCallbacks = [];
    $this->deferredServices = [];
    $this->reboundCallbacks = [];
    $this->serviceProviders = [];
    $this->resolvingCallbacks = [];
    $this->terminatingCallbacks = [];
    $this->beforeResolvingCallbacks = [];
    $this->afterResolvingCallbacks = [];
    $this->globalBeforeResolvingCallbacks = [];
    $this->globalResolvingCallbacks = [];
    $this->globalAfterResolvingCallbacks = [];
}
```

А это - содержимое `parent::flush()`:

```
public function flush()
{
    $this->aliases = [];
    $this->resolved = [];
    $this->bindings = [];
    $this->instances = [];
    $this->abstractAliases = [];
    $this->scopedInstances = [];
}
```

Как видите, происходит серьезная чистка экземпляра приложения, после которой мало что продолжает работать. Если закомментировать `$this->app->flush();`, ваш тест пройдет, но это также нарушит логику PHPUnit, в котором каждый тест должен быть независим, а значит "уборка" необходима.

Что можно посоветовать? Найти другой способ очистки кеша. Деструктор контроллера не подходит по этой же причине - выполняется после `tearDown()`. Попробуйте это:

```
public function __construct()
{
    CacheClearJob::dispatch()->afterResponse();
}
```

Comment: Да, все именно так как вы описали. Теперь я знаю что тестировать что то с register_shutdown_function() может быть не возможно. Ваш способ с ->afterResponse() помог.

Comment: @Arendach, да, конкретно `register_shutdown_function` невозможно протестировать. Но в самом PHPUnit много чего интересного. Он регистрирует свой обработчик ошибок `set_error_handler`. `afterResponse()` работает магическим образом - через деструктор. `$this->artisan("...", [])->expectsOutput()` также сделан интересным способом. Где-то используется рефлексия. В общем, довольно много магии, которую интересно изучать через сорцы PHPUnit. И добавлять свою, например через `setUpTraits()`